# Sending bytes from Android to PC Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm new to BT and I'd like to set up an environment where I can send a some bytes from my phone to the BT com port. Currently, I can successfully pair and connect to my BT headset. When I attempt to connect to the BT dongle on my PC, the Android socket connect() throws a "java.io.IOException: File descriptor in bad state" I'm looking for advice on successfully connecting Android to the PC, sending some bytes to the PC and watch them in a port monitor.

Here is my current state:

- The dongle is paired to the phone in the Android OS BT menu
- The dongle shows up in the Windows system tray
- I can both send and receive files over BT via share on Android and via "Send a file" in the Windows BT shell menu

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to put a server behind the PC's bluetooth. I used  [inthehand's](http://inthehand.com/)  software to provide that functionality.